# Treat Multiple Columns as 1 in SQL to Get Aggregates

Tags: sql, union

Is it possible to get counts, too? My UNIONs get me all distinct values across all 4 columns but now I need to know how many times each value appears across all 4 columns. Need to stay with stock SQL, if possible.

[image]

```
(SELECT DISTINCT classify1 AS classified FROM class) UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT classify2 AS classified FROM class) UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT classify3 AS classified FROM class) UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT classify4 AS classified FROM class)
ORDER BY classified
```

Returns:

A
B
C
D
E
F
H

Need:

A | 3
B | 3
C | 4
D | 3
E | 1
F | 1
H | 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4187c/5)

```
SELECT a.classified, COUNT(*)
FROM
(
  (SELECT classify1 AS classified FROM class) UNION ALL
  (SELECT classify2 AS classified FROM class) UNION ALL
  (SELECT classify3 AS classified FROM class) UNION ALL
  (SELECT classify4 AS classified FROM class)) a
GROUP BY a.classified
```

#### Result

```
| CLASSIFIED | COLUMN_1 |
-------------------------
|          A |        3 |
|          B |        3 |
|          C |        4 |
|          D |        3 |
|          E |        1 |
|          F |        1 |
|          H |        1 |
```

When you use `DISTINCT` you eliminate the extra 'A' in `classify3`

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`, the embed the result in a sub-query to perform your aggregate on.

```
SELECT
  classified,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
(
  (SELECT classify1 AS classified FROM class) UNION ALL
  (SELECT classify2 AS classified FROM class) UNION ALL
  (SELECT classify3 AS classified FROM class) UNION ALL
  (SELECT classify4 AS classified FROM class)
)
  AS unified_data
GROUP BY
  classified
ORDER BY
  classified
```